# Exe program which starts when device starts

Tags: python, exe, startup

I have a python script which I convert to an exe file. Does anybody knows some code for starting the program right after the device is startup?

Comment: What is "the device". You should show what effort you've done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your python program to exe using [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/)
If you are using windows, you can launch the exe during startup by:

> 1. Pressing Windows + R or RUN in the Start menu
> 2. Type `shell:startup` this opens a windows explorer
> 3. Paste the shortcut in the explorer

[Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to rightklick it and "add it to start"?

But this just works in that way when you are using windows.